# How to set a local password on Ubuntu server16.04 with Kerberos authentication?

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, kerberos

I use a Ubuntu server16.04 with Kerberos authentication on an ActiveDirectory server.

My user account on the Ubuntu doesn't have a local password,I deleted it once, but have a Kerberos password, so I want to add a local password for my account in case the ActiveDirectory server is down.

I tried as follows:

```
sudo passwd MYUSER
```

but it appeared to be able to change only Kerberos password...

```
Current Kerberos password:
Enter new Kerberos password:
Retype new Kerberos password:
```

Does anyone know how to add a new password in this situation?
I have a sudo authority.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Active Directory clients solve this by just caching the regular password.

- If you joined the computer using winbindd, consider installing [pam_ccreds](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpam-ccreds).
- If you are using SSSD, enable the `cache_credentials` option.

---

Password hashes in the 'shadow' file are independent of user account, so you could set a "local" password by:

1. adding a dummy user account (`useradd foo`),
2. setting its password (`passwd foo`),
3. manually editing `/etc/passwd` to list your username/UID/shell/homedir instead of that new account's (use `vipw`),
4. manually editing `/etc/shadow` to list your username instead of that new account (`vipw -s`).